# Pollution Control in City of 1900?

Tags: simcity-3000

I've started a new city in Sim City 3000, selected the starting date as 1900. Now, I created industrial zones and pollution is rising. However Environmental Ordinances or anything like that have not been invented yet. What should I do to control the pollution?

Comment: Obviously you should summon Godzilla and hope he stampedes through your industrial district. Are facetious comments allowed? Feel free to delete this if they aren't.

Comment: @RHINO_Mk.II lol, they are allowed. I _do_ have a sense of humour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For one thing, go green! Seriously, planting trees helps reduce pollution, so try to plant as many as you can and they should work to lower pollution.

You should try sending your trash to your neighbours, instead of collecting it in your landfills. That means you have one less source of pollution to worry about (and a very big one at that - the area around landfills become very polluted and the land value plummets).

Also, see if you can't get your industry to become more high-tech. I'm not sure if this is possible without environmental ordinances, but apart from that you need a high EQ (which comes with a lot of education). Maybe if you just got the EQ, the game will forgive no ordinances because they don't even exist yet.

Finally, try to reduce traffic, and obviously, don't make deals to host a nuclear waste plant =P

Source: 10 years of experience

You can look [here](http://simcity.wikia.com/wiki/Pollution) for details.

Comment: To push industry towards high tech increase industry taxes for manufacturing/heavy and lower it for hightech.

Comment: At the beginning of the game, I'd actually try to avoid any kind of more complex industry (so don't even try to attract high-tec at once). Go with large Areas of low industry to attract farms. Never had luck with attracting clean industries right away, although placing at least 3 field wide strips of trees helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've always done is place the high-polluting areas & buildings near an edge or corner of the map - and then surround them with 3-5 blocks thick of trees or parks.

This ensures that a half (or 3 quarters if in the corner) of pollution is shoved off to the neighbouring cities (out of sight, out of mind- right?) and the trees make sure the pollution that is in the city is pretty much reduced to that area.